# Angular 2 accessing PHP api, not returning json but returning file

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Angular 2 is accessing my php file with this code:

```
this._http.get('../api/src/1.0/get/images.php').subscribe(res => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(res));
});
```

Which gives this alert LocalHost:3000 Says

```
{
    "_body": "<?php\n\nrequire_once '../../orm/connection.php';\n\n$images = R::getAll( 'SELECT * FROM image');\nheader('Content-Type: application/json');\necho json_encode($images);\n\n?>\n",
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "Ok",
    "headers": {
        "Date": ["Sat",
        " 13 Feb 2016 21:11:26 GMT"],
        "Cache-Control": ["public",
        " max-age=0"],
        "Last-Modified": ["Sat",
        " 13 Feb 2016 20:39:49 GMT"],
        "Accept-Ranges": ["bytes"],
        "ETag": ["W/\"a7-152dc5c6608\""],
        "Content-Length": ["167"],
        "Content-Type": ["application/octet-stream"]
    },
    "type": 2,
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/api/src/1.0/get/images.php"
}
```

PHP File

```
<?php

require_once '../../orm/connection.php';

$images = R::getAll( 'SELECT * FROM image');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($images);

?>
```

I was expecting the alert to only contain the JSON data. 
If I go to the file directly via its url it only gives me the JSON data.
How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling static file at location `../api/src/1.0/get/images.php` and you get it's content.

You must run your .php file with server, than call it with `http.get(...)` You can use php localhost server with `php -S localhost:3333` you need to run this command in your project root ( php project )

Comment: So what you are saying is PHP is running localhost default port and Angular 2 is running localhost port 3000 and I need to run php on port 3000? Where would I use php -S localhost:3333 and why 3333?

Comment: Ah sorry, it was just example with :3333 you can use any... Best would be to run both client app ( angular 2) and api ( php ) with same server, just in different folders...

Comment: Makes sense. Worked fine once I went to the website on my default port!

Comment: I have same issue, running app(angular 2) on :3000 and placed php api inside app folder. Can you please suggest where to place php api and run on which port?

Comment: and want to post data.

Answer (score 1):

From the response you are getting, it looks like you are requesting `images.php` as `"Content-Type":["application/octet-stream"]`. Try configuring `http.get()` to ask for json:

```
const HEADER = { headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
this._http.get('../api/src/1.0/get/images.php', HEADER).subscribe(res => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(res));
});
```

Comment: Hmm still same with this header